# Can not disable sandbox mode for an app facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

My app work well in sandbox mode and I active SSL from Free service of `"COMODO CA Limited"`.
And also I have a `index.php` in `canvas` directory in root site with a simple content:

```
<?php
echo "Hello World!";
```

But when I disable sandbox mode, I get this error:

```
Error
URL must point to a secure page (i.e., the protocol used is 'https').
```

This is screen shot:
[image: facebook app error https]

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: maybe there is a problem with your ssl certificate. did you try to check it with a ssl service (e.g. https://sslcheck.globalsign.com/)?

Comment: I check my domain with that site, and give me 2 errors: `Server configuration does not include all intermediate certificates
Users may receive strong browser warnings and experience slow performance` and `Sessions may be vulnerable to BEAST attack
Attackers may be able to decrypt the encrypted SSL traffic`

Comment: try using https in canvas url

Comment: that means that your certificate is not ok and that you might need to get a valid one before you can disable sandbox mode.

Comment: @AbhishekAgarwal does not work